# Installing Super Hot

Tags: software-installation, games

I downloaded the linux build of Super Hot, I'm kinda new to Ubuntu, so I have no idea what to do with the files I've just downloaded...
It's a zip file, I extracted it to my desktop, and there were a file with a long name and a x86 extension, I renamed it to SUPERHOT.x86 if I would need to use a terminal...
I opened up the file and it started extracting .part2 files to the folder... I have no idea what to do next....
Link for page:

http://superhotgame.com/play-prototype

Direct Download:

http://superhotgame.com/SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux.zip

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder you extracted it to in the terminal, and just run it:

```
cd Linux
./SUPERHOT\ September\ 2013.x86
```

(Or whatever you renamed it to.)
Ran fine on my system. I didn't see any `.part2` files being extracted anywhere.

To get to a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. Navigate to your Desktop by typing these commands and pressing enter:

```
cd ~/Desktop/Linux
./SUPERHOT.x86
```

Comment: Uhhhh I'm kinda new to this terminal stuff...
The location of the file is:
/home/david/Desktop/Linux
what command should I run?

Comment: @Kachurman Answer updated.

Comment: @Kachurman There's a way to do this without running the terminal yourself, but that involves changing an option for executables in Nautilus' Preferences. And I don't remember the layout of that right now.

Comment: I know where to find the terminal, and I know some basic commands,
I just don't know why when I run this file, it opens up some sort of PyPar program that extracts files..

Comment: @Kachurman PyPar you say? There must be some log output to the terminal. Can you add those to the question?

Comment: Didn't see any error for `PyPar` . The progam though won't run if there is no data folder extracted. Refer to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can download SUPERHOT [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pg4l/files/SUPERHOT%20Prototype%20September%202013%20r1-x86.run/download?use_mirror=liquidtelecom) and after downloading, rename the file to
"SUPERHOT.run"

Open your terminal then run these commands (per line):

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x "SUPERHOT.run"
./"SUPERHOT.run"
```

**If** you're using 64-bit os and there's an error like mine:`libfuse.so.2:cannot open shared object file`, follow this:

1. Install 32-bit libraries

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
   ```
2. Install 32-bit libfuse package

   ```
   pushd /tmp/

   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fuse/libfuse2_2.8.1-1.1ubuntu2_i386.deb

   ar x libfuse2_2.8.1-1.1ubuntu2_i386.deb data.tar.gz

   tar -xhf data.tar.gz ./lib/libfuse.so.2.8.1

   sudo install -o root lib/libfuse.so.2.8.1 /lib32/libfuse.so.2

   rm lib/libfuse.so.2.8.1 data.tar.gz libfuse2_2.8.1-1.1ubuntu2_i386.deb

   rmdir lib

   sudo ldconfig

   popd
   ```
3. Run the SUPERHOT

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   chmod +x "SUPERHOT.run"
   ./"SUPERHOT.run"
   ```

   or you can just double-click the file if you already ran the above code.

That should work.

Comment: Don't mean to be overly harsh, but this is a too complex of a set up for simple procedure, as well as downloading the file from sourceforge, not from the official site.

Comment: Just incase someone downloaded from a sourceforge...

Answer (score 1):

Download SUPERHOT, unzip the file, then open the folder it made "Linux" right-click *SUPERHOT September 2013.x86* go to properties and under the permissions tab click "allow file executing as program". From there you should be able to open the games just by double clicking the SUPERHOT September 2013.x86 file.

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical way**

1. Download the file (You already did that, good!)
2. Extract *both* `SUPERHOT September 2013_Data` folder and the executable file `SUPERHOT September 2013.x86` to the same location.
3. Right click on the executable file, click Properties. A window will appear. Select `Permissions` tab. Check `Allow executing file as program`. Close the dialog.
4. Double lick to launch.

**Automated installation** (script that does same steps, just automatically):

Save this script as `superhot_installation.sh`, make it executable with `chmod +x superhot_installation.sh` , run as `./superhot_installation.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/Desktop/SUPERHOT
cd ~/Desktop/SUPERHOT
wget http://superhotgame-new.azurewebsites.net/BUILDS/SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux.zip 
unzip SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux.zip 
chmod +x "$HOME/Desktop/SUPERHOT/Linux/SUPERHOT September 2013.x86"
echo 'Done'
```

If you want to create a shortcut for the game, visit the question: [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/295286)